# Load data infile parameter error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

```sql
LOAD data LOCAL INFILE 
    'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/Uploads/amazon1.xml' 
INTO TABLE 
    amazonxmlfeeddata
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
LINES STARTING BY '<item_data>' TERMINATED BY '</item_data>' 
(@tmp)
SET
    item_unique_id = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//item_unique_id'),
    item_title = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//item_title'),
    item_long_desc = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//item_long_desc'),
    item_page_url = ExtractValue(@tmp, '//item_page_url');
```

This is basically my query and I wrote this is in ASP.NET C#. 
I want to execute this through C# in MySQL. 
But if I execute through C# it gives me error of (@tmp) that it should be declared. And even after declaring it still throws the same error.

Comment: "And even after declaring it still throws the same error." - Where the code for this statement?

Comment: You need to add a parameter "tmp" to the MySql command in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to add `AllowUserVariables=true;` to the MySql connection string, to allow user variables (`@tmp`).

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html